# How to configure the path to my Linux installation in GRUB (currently doing it manually at each boot)?

Tags: kali-linux, grub

So I have a laptop and I'm trying to get rid of my windows os and install kali linux.

Now I have done that but the problem is every time I turn on the computer it doesn't automatically go into the desktop environment it goes to the grub menu. Now I figured out the problem. The Problem is that it doesn't understand where to boot the instance from and I can go into the desktop by typing this[image]

Now the problem I'm having is this doesn't fix the whole problem every time I reboot my computer to get to the desktop I have to type all this again. I reinstalled grub but did not help.I also noticed that when I do sudo efibootmg there is a windows boot manager an Ubuntu one too but no kali. What can I do so it automatically sends me to the desktop when I turn on the computer?

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair You also can remove old UEFI boot entries: https://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer & may want to remove old /EFI/XXX folders in ESP. Each install has unique folder in ESP - efi system partition.

Comment: I tried to put in all the usefull info that I could think of if you need anything else let me know.  https://pastebin.com/6mxjaE1L here is the link

Comment: Boot-Repair essentially posts everything you manually posted, but a lot more in what we know as a standard format to review details.

Comment: Here you go https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RSCx3qnYDk/

Comment: When I ran the automatic repair it gave me this result:dpkg-error detected. Please open a terminal then type sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2" dpkg -- configure-a. I launched linux tried that command didn't work. I then went into the mnt directory and realised that there is nothing there and the nvme0n1p2 is actually located in the dev directory. After seeing this I tried doing sudo chroot "nvme0n1p2" dpkg -- configure-a when I was located in the dev directory and it said that nvme0n1p2 is not a directory

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu installed or just Kali? Your UEFI still has an Ubuntu UEFI entry, but UEFI keeps entries from deleted systems until manually deleted. Your p2 is your Kali install. Not sure if then Boot-Repair would correctly suggest fixes. If in Boot-Repair, it has already mounted partitions at /mnt/boot-save/.... But if you reboot, then you have to manually mount a partition and then use that path and probably need full chroot, so other partitions are mounted also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380

Comment: Kali linux itself says: **Kali linux is not the right linux distro for your use case** https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ Seriously, distros like Ubuntu or Fedora are much more useful to you – and easier to install!

Answer (score 0):

Update. The problem is solved honestly I have no idea what the actual problem was but I formatted the computer and downloaded kali again.Activated bootloader it suggested a different fix now this is what it said [image]

did this loaded up kali and it worked. Anyway hope this helps somebody.

Comment: It would be a good idea to crop the image prior to uploading.